# Running commands after event based outputs

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, bash-script

there are commands like

> iwevent

or

> tcpdump -n src host x.x.x.x

that send to the stdout some lines when something happens. Is there any form of running some command inmmediatly after a line is printed. Ex:

```
iwevent | echo "Wireless event happened"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read stdin in a loop

```
iwevent | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "[$(date "+%F %T")] - $line"
done
```

Depending on what you do in the loop body, you might want

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "[$(date "+%F %T")] - $line"
done < <(iwevent)
```

That avoids the implicit subshell effects of using a pipeline.

Comment: That's it, exactly like that! Thank you for answering! :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I get what you mean, but something in the direction of this?

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "$line" "Yohooo! One more package."
done < <(tcpdump -i any -nS)
```

Comment: I needed that, you understood me well. Thank you for answering!